# Reporting services: Forward dependencies are not valid

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have been tasked to update some reports and add new functionality but I have come across a problem.

There is currently a parameter drop-down list of Users and the first task is to allow this list to be sorted by either 'FirstName LastName', or 'LastName, FirstName'. This drop-down list is also a Parameter that sits next to the User drop-down.

There is therefore a dependency between the User drop-down and the SortOrder drop-down.

```
An error occurred during local report processing. The definition of the report '/Consulting_Absence' is invalid. The report parameter 'Usernames' has a DefaultValue or ValidValue that depends on the report parameter 'SortOrder'. Forward dependencies are not valid.
```

I don't precisely understand this error but I get the gist: you're not allowed to have one Parameter depend upon the value of another Parameter. Is that right?

Is this possible to achieve? I'm sure it must be but this is my first day looking at reports so I'm kinda programming in the dark.

I did read one post talking about creating a new data source but I didn't really understand it well enough to implement.

Hoping someone out there can help.

M

Answer (score 0):

I have made a discovery in the UI. There are little up and down arrows you can click to change the order of the Parameters. Moving the SortOrder to the top has done the trick, although now I'm am receiving a different error that is easier to sort.

M